# transitionend is not fired when initial state and final state are the same

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, css-transitions, transitionend

In the example below I'm doing `background-color` transition using CSS and trying to handle `transitionend` event for both divs.

Unfortunately, `transitionend` is not fired for `div2` as initial and final background colors are the same:

```js
var div1 = $('#div1');
var div2 = $('#div2');

$('#toggle').on('click', function() {
   div1.toggleClass('toggled');
   div2.toggleClass('toggled');
})

div1.on('transitionend', function() {
   console.log('div1 transitionend')
})

div2.on('transitionend', function() {
   console.log('div2 transitionend')
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.toggled {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div id="div1"></div>

<div id="div2"></div>

<button id="toggle">Toggle animation</button>
```

How can I achive handling `transitionend` even in cases when initial state and final state are the same?

Comment: If I am not wrong, a transition is triggered only when the values are different. So, if a transition itself doesn't happen then I don't think there is any chance of that event getting triggered.

Comment: Any reference to the specs? I can't find anything related to my question

Comment: Nope, its more how I expect browsers to work. Starting a transition event when there is nothing to transition is an overkill. I don't think the specs would have defined anything for *when to start a transition*, they'd have left it to implementation but I'll check it up for you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A transition generally occurs when a [style-change-event](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#style-change-event) occurs. That is, when the style of an element (a property or more's value) changes, the transition is started. The W3C Specs (as expected) doesn't define when a style change event is triggered and leaves it to the implementation.

Below is the most that I could find in [W3C Specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#style-change-event) about this particular topic (2<sup>nd</sup> para below anchor):

> When a style change event occurs, ***implementations must start transitions based on the computed values that changed*** in that event.

Actually the below seems to be even more conclusive definition of when a transition should start. This is found towards the end of the section pointed to by [this anchor](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#starting):

> If all of the following are true:
>
> - the element does not have a running transition for the property,
> - the ***before-change style is different from*** and can be interpolated with the ***after-change style for that property***,
> - the element does not have a completed transition for the property or the end value of the completed transition is different from the after-change style for the property,
> - there is a matching transition-property value, and
> - the combined duration is greater than 0s,
>
> then implementations must remove the completed transition (if present) from the set of completed transitions ***and start a transition whose***:
>
> - start time is the time of the style change event plus the matching transition delay,
> - end time is the start time plus the matching transition duration,
> - start value is the value of the transitioning property in the before-change style,
> - end value is the value of the transitioning property in the after-change style,
> - reversing-adjusted start value is the same as the start value, and
>     reversing shortening factor is 1.

---

Now based on my understanding of how UAs work and how they would have been optimized, I do not see any reason for them to fire a transition start event when none of the properties set on the element is undergoing a change. It would be a overkill and extra load on the UA which could easily be avoided. When there is no transition start event itself, there is almost no way that a transition end event will be fired in such cases.

So, it looks like you'd most likely have to use some dummy property changes (or) use a timer whose value is equal to the `transition-duration` + `transition-delay` to mimic the `transitionend`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Harry, really nice and precise answer!